# Changing Button using setBackgroundDrawable, but background stays changed when returning

Tags: android

I'm using the `setBackgroundDrawable` method to change the background of the button on my Activity. The onClickListener also has an Intent to open up a new Activity. However, when I return to the past Activity by hitting the physical back button, the button with the onClickListener assigned to it still has the onClick background set. If I return to the previous Activity by using the back button in the Action Bar, it works correctly. I tried to use a selector XML, but Android Studio gives me render errors, and it doesn't load when I compile.

Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.jordandebarth.supercalculator;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton pythag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33b5e5")));

        final ImageButton pythag = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pythag_button);


        pythag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                pythag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pythag_button_selector);
                Intent pythagIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,       PythagoreanActivity.class);
                startActivity(pythagIntent);

            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e5e5e5"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pythag_button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pythag_button"
    android:focusable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**user selector in xml file :**

**button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_hover" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_hover" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_hover" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
</selector>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="@string/yes" />
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a render error in Eclipse, and it says The following classes could not be found:
- Button (Change to android.widget.Button, Fix Build Path, Edit XML).